# import .csv to update database with .sh

Tags: shell, csv

when I try to run this i get error 1064 (42000) error at line 38: you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql vrsion for the right syntax to use near EOF>> line 1
-Bash:syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
#!/bin/bash
# Import csv into mysql
mysql -uroot -p0psupply Catalog <<EOF

# Remove old backup table
DROP TABLE parts_backup;

# Backup old parts table
CREATE TABLE parts_backup ( 
    sku varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Standard Part Num',
    src varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ALL' COMMENT 'not used',
    item varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FACTS Num',
    _IF varchar(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'not used',
    _UM varchar(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unit of Measure',
    description varchar(75) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description',
    floor decimal(5,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Floor price',
    usa decimal(5,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'USA Dealer Net',
    can decimal(5,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Canada Dealer Net',
    high decimal(5,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Highest selling price',
    available int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'units available (not used)',
    commission float(3,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'commission',
    class varchar(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'item class',
    active varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'active?',
    in_n_out varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'In & Out'
    )
ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

INSERT INTO parts_backup SELECT * FROM parts;

# Create brand new parts table by clearing old one
TRUNCATE parts;

# upload CSV file
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'parts.csv'
INTO TABLE parts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
#(sku, src, item, _IF, _UM, description, floor, usa, can, high, available);

# done
EOF>>
```

Comment: lin 38: #(sku, src, item, _IF, _UM, description, floor, usa, can, high, available);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line should simply be

```
EOF
```

not

```
EOF>>
```